# I have a S3 Bucket and want to create a lifecycle configuration to delete objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

I have folder structure something like this:-

```
*/*/SUCCESS
*/*/FAILED
```

how can i apply expiration rule on it such that *- could any name for the folder and is dynamically created through code.

I have tried SUCCESS as Prefix but have utterly **failed**.

Any help would be great as I am new to AWS

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since you must specify a `Prefix`. You could try using a Prefix of `*/*/SUCCESS/`. Let us know if it works! See also: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116487

Comment: @john Its not working .Does aws provides any other solution using Tags .

Comment: Yes, you can specify object tags instead of a path prefix. Thus, it could delete objects with a given set of tags. Alternatively, you could write your own script that deletes objects and run it at regular intervals. This could even be done as a scheduled Lambda function.